# listView.setSelection(n); m=listView.getSelectedItemPosition(); //m != n. why?

Tags: android, api, listview

calling ListView's setSelection() seems to have a problem. a lot of people ask about it. there are answers but none is working. ignoring issues of visual affects. here's a basic scenario that results in unexpected results:

```
listView.setSelection(5); //listView is a ListView. there are >= 6 items in the list
int sel=listView.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

you would expect sel==5 but actually it's -1 (which method didn't work?)
so is this a bug and if not, what are the rules that govern the setting and retrieval of the selected item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see in the documentation of setSelection you find this:

> Sets the currently selected item. If
>   in touch mode, the item will not be
>   selected but it will still be
>   positioned appropriately. If the
>   specified selection position is less
>   than 0, then the item at position 0
>   will be selected.

That way, it makes perfectly sense that it returns -1. The item is not selected even if you run this method when you're in touch mode, as you most likely are.

Comment: what does it mean **but it will still be positioned appropriately** ?

Comment: I haven't tried it out, but I guess it means the item will be in the center of the screen, or at least it will be in view.

Comment: thanks. i wonder if it wouldn't make more sense for the setSelection method to throw RuntimeException if it's not doing anything because of the mode that it's currently in (touch mode). that might save a lot of time and questions as the call behaves as if everything is normal and it has executed what you asked it to....

Comment: It'd be nice if you accepted the answer if you feel it was the correct one for you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Eric's answer.  However, if you still want to make it work, here is a work around.

for your onItemClick part use the following (I had multiple listviews...)

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View v, int chosenPosition, long     
myLong) {
    switch(parentView.getId()){
    case R.id.Hrlist:
        parentView.setSelection(chosenPosition);
        break;
    case R.id.Minlist:
        parentView.setSelection(chosenPosition);
        break;
    case R.id.Seclist:
        parentView.setSelection(chosenPosition);
    }
}
```

Then in your other method you can use something along the lines of:

```
HrList.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Assuming HrList is defined as

```
ListView HrList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Hrlist);
```

So yes, in touch mode it doesn't register the item as selected.  However, it does move it to a dependable location (i.e. at the top) which you can use to get the value.